# Changing flavour of a kibble within one brand

Tags: dogs, diet

We went through 4 kinds of kibble with my dog and finally found the one he likes (it is grain-free kibble, with 70% meat and 30% veggies and herbs). Through the first change, because I lacked some information, we had some problems with his stool and gas (I feel bad about it; we went back to the previous kibble for a while then). Afterwards, we tried to transition more gradually to help him get used to the new food.

I was wondering, if I want to change flavor of the kibble within the same brand and the same line of dog food, should I do it gradually as recommended by many vets for changing dog food? I don't want to cause him any more distress, but is it different enough to cause him gastrointestinal problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were my dog, just to be safe I'd do it gradually across four to seven days, especially since I know the dog has a history of gastrointestinal problems. During the nine and a half years I had my dog, I changed food several times and developed an easy system. I used seven empty peanut butter jars, labeled them Day 1, Day 2, through to Day 7.

In the jar for Day 1, I'd put mostly old food and a bit of new food. In Day 2, I'd increase it slightly. By the middle jar, Day 4, it would be half-and-half. Day 7 was the reverse of Day 1. I'd do this before the old bag was empty, then leave these jars sitting in a row in order. That way, when the old bag was empty everything was set to transition into the new bag.  No worries that I didn't leave enough for a proper transition.

Often, I'd have a bit of kibble left over at the end of the old bag. I'd get another jar and fit it into the row of jars where it fit best. I remember one time half a day's ration was left so I fit it into the middle and filled it from the new bag. I then labeled it Day 3.1 or something weird that I knew meant it should go between Day 3 and Day 4. It doesn't hurt the dog to transition one day longer.

Transitioning might not be necessary, given the parameters you mention but like I said, if it were my dog I'd do it to be safe. On the other hand, if you see your vet in the meantime you could ask them for advice.

Comment: Thanks, and great idea with jars :-) I think I will talk to my vet as well, since I planned to visit him soon, and I will comment what they told me, but transitioning seems reasonable.